# mapping Handsontable to MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, handsontable

I have built a excel sheet like structure using HandsonTable. I have to store this information in a MySQL table. Does anybody have any recommendations on what is the best table design to store this information? Thanks!

Comment: This really needs more information. What's your project setup? How are you planing on using stored data? Do you store other data in your DB?

Comment: I stored the content of the table in a single longtext field in MYSQL.